# how to add the selected files from dialog window to a dictionary?

Tags: python, file, dictionary, dialog, window

I wish it's able to open a dialog window and select my files,

```
a.txt
b.txt
```

then add them in my dictionary

```
myDict = { "a.txt" : 0,
           "b.txt" : 1}
```

I searched on website

```
import Tkinter,tkFileDialog
root = Tkinter.Tk()
filez = tkFileDialog.askopenfilenames(parent=root,multiple='multiple',title='Choose a file')
```

these codes work for opening a dialog window and selecting my files.
But the question is how to add the selected files to the dictionary?

With Stephan's answer, the problem is solved

```
myDict = {}
for filename in filez:
    myDict[filename] = len(myDict)
    print "myDict: " + str(myDict)
```

Now the myDict is

```
myDict = {'C:/a.txt': 0}
myDict = {'C:/a.txt': 0, 'C:/b.txt': 1}
```

After searching online, just add os.path.split

```
myDict = {}
for filename in filez:
    head, tail = os.path.split(str(filename))
    myDict[tail] = len(myDict)
```

Now everything is right

```
myDict = {'a.txt': 0, 'b.txt': 1}
```

I got the myDict without path, problem solved!
Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
myDict = {}
myDict[filenameFromDialog] = len(myDict)
```

That is the syntax for adding to a dictionary.

If you have an array of files you want to add to the dictionary, you could loop over the list and add them one at a time:

```
myDict = {}
for filename in filez:
    myDict[filename] = len(myDict)
```

Comment: Thanks, it works. only need to delete parentheses in the for sentence.