# How to close IDLE window which is opened by Tkinter.Tk()

Tags: python, tkinter, tk-toolkit

From my last question, [how to add the selected files from dialog window to a dictionary?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17580764/how-to-add-the-selected-files-from-dialog-window-to-a-dictionary), I opened an another IDLE window, which has nothing (no menu and command)

```
   import Tkinter,tkFileDialog
   root = Tkinter.Tk()
```

How could I close this window?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This was originally a comment, but it seems to be what you need, so:

I'm not 100% sure, but from what I can gather from your post, I think what you're looking for is `root.destroy()`

Comment: Thanks, it works. I just found the command root.destroy() works for my case few minutes ago! An another command root.quit() quits from my main Idle window.

Answer (score 0):

As @inspectorG4dget says, you can use `root.destroy()`, but that is for destroying a widget and all it's children. If you mean by "closing the window" that you actually want to shut down your program, you should use `root.quit()`.

So for that I created you an example, where I binded the <kbd>ESC</kbd> button to the quitter function:

```
import Tkinter as tk

def quit(obj):
    obj.quit()

root = tk.Tk()
root.bind('<Escape>', lambda e: quit(root))
root.mainloop()
```

So after you program is running, if you hit the <kbd>ESC</kbd> it will quit.

Anyway, for further info **RTFM**: Tk Interface Book