# User select files dialog- python 2.7

Tags: python-2.7, tkinter

My python script prompts the user to select a list of files using `askopenfilenames`.  The remainder of the script performs some uninteresting file operations.

```
from Tkinter import *
import tkFileDialog

root = Tk()
root.withdraw()

inputFiles = tkFileDialog.askopenfilenames()
fileList = root.tk.splitlist(inputFiles)
```

From tests I can select up to 186 files and the script works.  If I try to select 187, then `inputFiles` comes back empty but no error is generated.

My file names are quite long;

`C:/J/Projects/Proj_Name/cmbrUkPr_038_LINE_MON-DE-05_MIN_PHASE_SHOT_FFID_21.sgy`

Using `sys.getsizeof(inputFiles)` returns `30742` so it's not a memory issue.

I can't find anything in the docs about a limit on the number of files that can be opened.  I am using windows so `inputFiles` is returned as a Unicode type.

Can anyone suggest an alternative that won't limit the number of files selected?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17863290/quantity-limitation-for-dialog-window-selecting-files Have you checked this one?

Comment: @Lafexlos I have now, thank you.  As martineau mentions, the problem still persists with a large number of files and I can't find a suitable alternative other than using `shell.SHBrowseForFolder` which isn't as versatile.